# How are resonating valence bond (RVB) states related to fractional quantum Hall (FQH) states?

Tags: condensed-matter, research-level, quantum-hall-effect

In Kalmeyer and Laughlin's paper, there is an argument made for a frustrated two-dimensional Heisenberg antiferromagnet on a triangular lattice that if one uses a FQH wavefunction for bosons to represent the ground state, the variation energy estimate is nearly the same as if one uses RVB state to represent the ground state. There is an entire explanation for how the spins on the lattice can be imagined as a lattice gas of "hard-core" bosons, and along with a gauge transformation, one can imagine the frustrated Heisenberg Hamiltonian as similar to the FQH Hamiltonian.

However, I do not see how this exactly relates to the RVB state. Yes, the variational energies of the RVB and FQH Hamiltonians are very close, but why physically is this true? How is the FQH wavefunction for bosons related to the RVB ground state (which represents all possible coverings of this lattice using $S=0$ singlet states)?